# Migration odoo, Style error Could not get content

Tags: odoo, database-migration, odoo-15

I upgraded the database to Odoo 15 but I still got this error:

```
Style error

The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.

Could not get content for /web/static/src/scss/webclient.scss defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.
```

[image]

and the log of browser:

```
Could not get content for /web_gantt_native/static/src/js/gantt_item_sorted.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:27116:9
Could not get content for /web_gantt_native/static/src/js/gantt_item.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:27119:9
Could not get content for /knowsystem/static/src/js/knowsystem_action_manager.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28037:9
Could not get content for /knowsystem/static/src/js/knowsystem_readonly_formcontroller.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28040:9
Could not get content for /knowsystem/static/src/js/knowsystem_readonly_formview.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28043:9
Could not get content for /knowsystem/static/src/js/sidebar.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28046:9
Could not get content for /web_notify/static/src/js/web_client.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28980:9
Could not get content for /web_notify/static/src/js/widgets/notification.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'. web.assets_backend.min.js:28983:9
```

I already looked for the files but didn't find them in the addons src files also removed the ir_attachemnts for all js !
Any one got this error before and found a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

#### Cause of the issue

This issue happens when static files no longer exist in a newer version of an app. After the migration is performed the assets bundles still expect to find them.

#### Solution

You can just delete those asset objects from shell for example(and do the same with the rest):

```py
env['ir.asset'].search([('path', '=', '/web_gantt_native/static/src/js/gantt_item_sorted.js')]).unlink()
env.cr.commit()
```

If the record does not exist on the database add the static file as explained in the alternative solution.

#### Alternative Solution

Temporarily create those files. For example in your case create an empty file `/web_gantt_native/static/src/js/gantt_item_sorted.js` and `include`(Odoo [Assets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/saas-15.2/fr/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html) documentation) it in `web.assets_backend`. Once that is done, the issue should be gone and the database should run normal.

Comment: Great answer @Kareem, just to not if you have access to the database you can directly run `update ir_asset set active=False where path='/web_gantt_native/static/src/js/gantt_item_sorted.js';`

Answer (score -1):

The answer provided looks fine, I just want to add that you can using the developer mode use the "regenerate asset bundle" feature that will help you with those kinds of assets issues.

Comment: You shoud add this as comment to the correct answer or mention the name of the person who gave the correct answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33143548)